Changing Default Email Address in Azure AD B2C User Flows Without Custom Policies
We are using Azure AD B2C for our identity and access management, and we've run into an issue regarding the default email address used for communications. Currently, Azure AD B2C sends emails from msonlineservicesteam@microsoftonline.com, but we would like to change this to our custom domain email, example@domain.com.
From my research, it appears that this can be achieved by implementing custom policies in Azure AD B2C. However, this would require us to rewrite all our existing user flows from scratch, which is a very time-consuming process for what seems like a minor change.
My Question:
Is there a way to change the default email address in Azure AD B2C user flows without having to use custom policies? Any simpler solutions or workarounds would be highly appreciated.
Context:

We are currently using built-in user flows provided by Azure AD B2C.
We want to avoid the complexity and maintenance overhead of custom policies if possible.

What I’ve Tried/Considered:

Reviewing Azure AD B2C documentation and settings for a straightforward configuration option, but haven't found any solutions that don't involve custom policies.
Exploring potential third-party tools or integrations, though I prefer a native solution if available.

If anyone has successfully managed to change the default email address in user flows without resorting to custom policies, please share your experience or point me in the right direction. Thank you!

Changing the default email address used for communications in Azure AD B2C user flows cannot be achieved without using custom policies

The built-in user flows provided by Azure AD B2C use the default email address msonlineservicesteam@microsoftonline.com for communications, and this cannot be changed without implementing custom policies


Note that: Changing the default email address used for communications in Azure AD B2C user flows cannot be achieved without using custom policies.


The built-in user flows provided by Azure AD B2C use the default email address msonlineservicesteam@microsoftonline.com for communications, and this cannot be changed without implementing custom policies.
As the default email address is hardcoded in the built-in user flows and cannot be changed without modifying the policies.

Hence to change the default email address, you need to either make use of custom policies or any third-party application.

Custom policies provide greater flexibility and customization when compared to built-in user flows.
Or third-party email providers like Mailjet, SendGrid, or SparkPost.

Refer this GitHub blog to do it via custom policy.
Reference:
B2C "From Address" Display Name - Microsoft Q&A by Alfredo Revilla

Unfortunately, this is not supported with the out-of-box user journeys.
However, should you wish to implement this with custom policies, you can follow this implementation sample: B2C Samples - Change local account sign-in name (email address).
Custom policies (aka identity experience framework policies) can live alongside your user journey flows, therefore you do not need to move everything across to custom policies to implement the above sample.
An easy way to get started with custom policies is to use the Azure AD B2C IEF setup website.
